# Regex: Why doesn't @"^([0-9]|10)" match '10'?

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to validate that a text box contains only numbers between `0` and `10`.

This is the regex I am currently using:

```
@"^([0-9]|10)"
```

But it only matches `0-9`.  What should I change to make it match `10`??

Thanks!

Comment: It seems it matches '1' first, so after that it stops matching =)

Comment: Yeah, deleting my answer.  It does "Match" 10, but the match isn't the value 10, it's actually just matching the 1.  The match is still successful.  The problem is, is that this regex, even reversed, will also match 15 or 584, but that the value matched will only be the first character.  You probably need to constrain it more to get what you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `1` from `10` is matched by `[0-9]` because the regex engine matches from left to right. And since you only anchored the beginning-of-input : `^`, the engine is satisfied if the `1` is matched.

There are two solutions.

### 1 - Swap it:

```
@"^(10|[0-9])"
```

or

### 2 - anchor it with `$`:

```
@"^([0-9]|10)$"
```

Comment: @Sachin: added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(10|[0-9])
```

Because the [0-9] was first matching the 1 of the 10.

Answer (score 1):

It might be "lazy", matching the first potential match, i.e. "1" vs. "10". Perhaps try switching the order:

```
"^(10|[0-9])"
```

This means the regex will check for '10' first, and will check for [0-9] only if there is no '10'

If that doesn't work, there may be a flag you can

Answer (score 0):

Use this  @"^(10|[0-9])". Other way it will treat 1 of 10 as first match from first condition and so does not fall on OR condition.